Does running individual Tukey tests makes a difference or should I treat my simple as a multiple comparison in only one Tukey test?
Hi I need to run Tukey analysis to compare the quantification of 30 metabolites using 3 different types of hydrolysis (lets say hydrolysis A,B and C). so I am thinking in running 30 separate Tukey tests (to compare each metabolite with hydrolysis A, B and C). my question is if as my Ho will be the same for the 30 metabolites, should I run 30 individual Tukey tests or should I compare all the 30 metabolites in only 1 Tukey tests to compare the 3 types of hydrolysis?.
I am not interested in knowing if there are differences among all the metabolites but only in finding differences among the types of hydrolysis for each metabolite

Tukey deserves to have his name capitalized.  Please state the global aim of the analysis.  State why statistical tests are of interest, vs. estimates.

thanks for your advice about capital letters.. my interest is to see if there are or not significant differences in each metabolite when they were hydrolysed from 3 different methods. so I do not know if I should run 30 individual Tukey analysis or if I should run an individial Tukey analysis to compare all the 30 metabolites analysed for hydrolysis A, B and C

Please describe the biomedical goals and aims, not in statistical terms.  And note that seeking 'statistical significance' is not a very noble goal, being arbitrary and devoid of biological significance.

hi thanks for your help. this is one of many experiments I needed to run during my project. the aim of the project is to evaluate if "X plant sample" has the potential to deliver bioactive compounds that may have a positive effect on human health. in this experiment we evaluated the metabolism (hydrolysis) of bioactive compounds of X plant with faecal samples over time (0, 24 and 48 hours). that is exactly what I did. we were interested in knowing if each of the metabolites can be metabolized differently over time (but not differences among metabolites).
